# Count characters in contentEditable DIV

Tags: jquery, counter, contenteditable

I'm using this Plugin to count chars on inputs and textareas: http://cssglobe.com/post/7161/jquery-plugin-simplest-twitterlike-dynamic-character-count-for-textareas

I would need to count characters also in a DIV with the setting "contentEditable" set to True.

Is this possible modifiying this Plugin?

I think I would need to change something in this line:

```
            var count = $(obj).val().length;
```

But i really don't know how the contentEditable works... Any idea?

Thanks!

Edit:

I'm doing this as brettz9 suggested:

```
var method = $.inArray(obj.nodeName.toLowerCase(), ['textarea', 'input']) !== -1 ? 'val' : 'text';
var count = $(obj)[method]().length;
```

I just have one little problem on doing this for other field I required t have a min/max lenght (I have one input and one contentEditable)

This is that conditional part:

```
                if (other_required){
                if ($(other_required).val().length > 0 && available >= 0){
                    $(submit_button).attr("disabled", "");
                } else {
                    $(submit_button).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
```

i don't know how to declare that [method] var and use it with "other_required"

Comment: "[method]" is allowing the method string ("val" or "text") to be used as the dynamic name of the method, depending on whether the element is a textarea (or input) or not. It is thus equivalent to $(obj).text() or $(obj).val() depending on the nodeName (the type of element). For above, you can replace ".val()" with "[method]()" and then on the line above, set "method" to "val" or "text" as I did. At least this is what i understand u want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
// We'll assume it is contenteditable (which uses text, or could also use html (innerHTML) if you wanted to count markup length) 
//  if it is not a textarea or input (which uses value)
var method = $.inArray(obj.nodeName.toLowerCase(), ['textarea', 'input']) !== -1 ? 'val' : 'text';
var count = $(obj)[method]().length;
```

Comment: Thanks brettz, that works perfect... I have just one problem with one modification I've made to the plugin to require multiple inputs min/max lenghts... It's something like "if (other_required){ if ($(other_required).val().length > 0 && available >= 0){ $(submit_button).attr("disabled", ""); } }" I don't know how to call the [method] var for that instance and that "other_required" object (Because I have 1 input and 1 contentEditable now)

Answer (score 4):

`val()` is used to get input values such as textarea, textbox, etc. Try `text()` instead.

EDIT:

Try this:

```
function count(obj) {
  var method = $.inArray(obj.nodeName.toLowerCase(), 
    ['textarea', 'input']) !== -1 ? 'val' : 'text';
  return $(obj)[method]().length;
}
```

And your code would look like:

```
if (other_required){
if (count(other_required) > 0 && available >= 0){
    $(submit_button).attr("disabled", "");
} else {
    $(submit_button).attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```